# Pass variable to another view

Tags: iphone, variables, sdk, view

I'm trying to set a variable in another view.

I'm in a view which I have named ProgramViewController and from here I would like to set a variable named `bands` in MyViewController.

I thought it would be as simple as

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
myViewController.bands = @"hello world";
[myViewController release];
```

And in the header of MyViewController:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSString *bands;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bands;
```

That does not work, though.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I synthesize `bands` in MyViewController:

```
@synthesize pageNumberLabel, tableProgram, bands;
```

But when trying to print it with `NSLog` in the viewDidLoad of MyViewController I get `(null)`

`NSLog(@"%@", bands);`

Comment: Can you post your whole code related to MyViewController allocation, presentation, ...? I mean the part, which is in your ProgramViewController and is responsible for MyViewController presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in another way. I managed to load the data in MyViewController instead. I was dealing with a page controller and had to populate a UITableView but had troubles loading the data.

This is solved in a completely other way now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synthesize the bands variable in MyViewController.m

```
@synthesize bands;
```

A variable needs to be synthesize in order to use it as a public property outsize of a class in Objective-C

Comment: I have done so. I propably should have mentioned that. Sorry. `@synthesize pageNumberLabel, tableProgram, bands;` But when calling `bands` in viewDidLoad I get `(null)`. `NSLog(@"%@", bands);`